# Team Foundation Server 2012 Express Product Key

Tags: tfs

Okay, so I just downloaded TFS 2012 Express and it's asking me to choose trial or enter a product key.

I've searching to find out how to obtain an Express key (like I've had to do with previous express products).

Comment: Is there a cancel button or order license button ? That might work like it does with the VS trial versions: http://blogs.infosupport.com/what-product-key-do-i-need-to-use-for-visual-studio-2012-trial-evaluation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the key on **MSDN Subscriber Downloads**.

Here:

[image]